# After render threw an error in 'c:helloForeach' [Cannot read property 'id' of undefined]

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am getting error when I am trying to display my LWC on Home page:below is error[image: LWC error]
I am trying  to add list of contacts and  giving them color at top & bttom of list through CSS.

A] html code:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="HelloForEach">
        <ul class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <template iterator:it={contacts}> 
                <li key={id.value.id}>
                    <div if:true={it.first} class="list-first"></div>   
                    {it.value.Name},{it.value.Title}
                    <div if:true={it.last} class="list-last"></div>    
                </li> 
             </template> 
        </ul>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

B] js code:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class HelloForeach extends LightningElement {
   contacts=[
       {
           Id:1,
           Name:'Edmond Nil',
           Title:'Technical Architecht'
       },
       {
           Id:2,
           Name:'Derren Oswalts',
           Title:'Sales Manager'
       },
       {
           Id:3,
           Name:'Dorothy kentwill',
           Title:'Head Desirner'
       },
       {
           Id:4,
           Name:'AmitMane',
           Title:'CEO & Founder'
       }
   ]
}
```

C] CSS code

```
    e.list-first
{
    border-top: 5px solid red;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.list-last
{
    border-bottom: 5px solid greenyellow;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

D] xmlcode:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
       <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
<li key={id.value.id}>
```

by

```
 <li key={it.value.Id}>
```

Comment: NO it doesnt  work i have  replaced <li key={id.value.id}> to <li key={it.value.Id}> .WHy it says Id undefined ??

Comment: Look at this [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/9622_Z2T-/edit). Tell me if you still have the problem.

Comment: I did made  same change as you suggested But it still the the same .If youwant i can show u my real time code and  application on google meeting .addme on gmail. We can have small meeting amitm222@gmail.com

Comment: @AM_SFDC post your code so we can figure out where is the problem.

Comment: Hey Klecool ,I just  Re saved  and depployed my components  its working fine though i didnt  get why was the  error in forst place .BTW Thanks

Comment: I would say a priori a cache problem [here how to fix it](https://medium.com/salestrip/salesforce-lightning-component-caching-a39b6a9d01a7)